# Observe, ObserveForever Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Estoy realizando una aplicación de balizas utilizo la libreria de Beacon, en la clase necesito hacer operaciones en base de datos locales, veo que no puedo utilizar un observe, pues no extiende de AppCompatActivity, sin embargo al utilizar observeForever realiza un ciclo lo cual no quiero, he leido que puedo crear mi LifecycleOwner pero no logro entenderle.

```
private fun guardaAlertaLocal(id_persona:String, latitude:Double, longitude:Double, estadoAlarma:Int){
    val time = Calendar.getInstance().time
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val current = formatter.format(time)

    var guardaAlerta: GuardaAlertasInternal= GuardaAlertasInternal(id_persona,latitude!!,longitude!!,estadoAlarma,current);
    val macDatabase=MacDatabase.getInstance(getContext())

    macDatabase.listAlertaDao().getAlertas().observeForever(Observer {
            listAlerts->
        if(!listAlerts.isEmpty()) {
            var fecha= (listAlerts[0].date)
            if (fecha.equals(current)){
                toast("entre a guardar")
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    macDatabase.listAlertaDao().GuardaAlerta(guardaAlerta)
                }
            }else{
                toast("entre a eliminar")
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    macDatabase.listAlertaDao().deleteAlertas()
                }
            }
        }else{
            toast("daaa")
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                macDatabase.listAlertaDao().GuardaAlerta(guardaAlerta)
            }
        }
    })


}
```

Soy nueva en esto

Comment: ya pude al parecer solo era cuestión de crear una función que removiera el `observerForever`